# Python 'for loop' will not export all records

Tags: python-3.x, oracle

I have a Python program that executes an Oracle stored procedure.  The SP creates a temp table and then the Python program queries that table and writes the data to an XML file with formatting.

Forgive the noob question, but for some reason the for loop that I'm using to export to the XML file does not export all records.  If I limit the query that creates the XML to 15 rows, it works and creates the file.  For any value above 15, the program completes, but the file isn't created.

However, this isn't always consistent.  If I do multiple runs for 15, 16, or 17 rows, I get a file.  But if I try 20, no file is created.  No errors, just no file.

This was the initial code. The 'sql' runs against an Oracle private temp table and formats the XML:

```
cursor.execute(sql)
rows = cursor.fetchall()

with open(filename, 'a') as f:
 f.write('<ROWSET>')
 for row in rows:
  f.write(" ".join(row))
f.write('</ROWSET>')

cursor.close()
```

Then I changed it to this, but again, no file is created:

```
cursor.execute(sql)

with open(filename, 'a') as f:
 f.write('<ROWSET>')
 while True:
  rows = cursor.fechmany(15)
 for row in rows:
  f.write(" ".join(row))
 f.write('</ROWSET>')

cursor.close()
```

I've run the 'free' command and reviewed it with my DBA, and it doesn't appear to be a memory issue.  The typical size of the output table is about 600 rows. The table itself has 36 columns.

The indentation may not look right the way I've pasted it here, but the program does work.  I just need a way to export all rows.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

I'm on a Linux box using Python 3.8.5.

Here is the query (minus proprietary information) that is executed against the temp table in the cursor.execute(sql):

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT("ROW",
                XMLFOREST(
                carrier_cd,
                prscrbr_full_name,
                prscrbr_first_name,
                prscrbr_last_name,
                d_phys_mstr_id,
                prscrbr_id,
                prscrbr_addr_line_1,
                prscrbr_addr_line_2,
                prscrbr_city,
                prscrbr_state_cd,
                prscrbr_zip,
                specialty_cd_1,
                specialty,
                unique_patient_reviewed,
                patient_count_db_oral,
                patient_count_cv_aa,
                patient_count_cv_lipo,
                PDC_DIABETES,
                PDC_HTN,
                PDC_STATINS,
                Rating_Diabetes,
                Rating_HTN,
                Rating_Statins,
                PDC_DIABETES,
                PDC_HTN,
                PDC_STATINS,
                M_PC_DB_ORAL,
                M_PC_CV_AA,
                M_PC_CV_LIPO,
                M_PDC_DIABETES,
                M_PDC_HTN,
                M_PDC_STATINS
                ),
                XMLAGG
                                                (
                XMLFOREST(
                        case when carrier_hq_cd is not null
                        then XMLConcat(
                                XMLELEMENT("PATIENT_ID", patient_id),
                                XMLELEMENT("PATIENT_NAME", patient_name),
                                XMLELEMENT("DOB", dob),
                                XMLELEMENT("PHONE_NO", phone_no),
                                XMLELEMENT("MEMBER_PDC_DIABETES", MEMBER_PDC_DIABETES),
                                XMLELEMENT("MEMBER_PDC_HTN", MEMBER_PDC_HTN),
                                XMLELEMENT("MEMBER_PDC_STATINS", MEMBER_PDC_STATINS)
                                        )
                        end "PATIENT_INFO"
                                    )
                                ORDER BY patient_id
                                )
                            )XMLOUT
 FROM ORA$PTT_QCARD_TEMP
 GROUP BY
           carrier_cd,
           prscrbr_full_name,
           prscrbr_first_name,
           prscrbr_last_name,
           d_phys_mstr_id,
           prscrbr_id,
           prscrbr_addr_line_1,
           prscrbr_addr_line_2,
           prscrbr_city,
           prscrbr_state_cd,
           prscrbr_zip,
           specialty_cd_1,
           specialty,
           unique_patient_reviewed,
           patient_count_db_oral,
           patient_count_cv_aa,
           patient_count_cv_lipo,
           PDC_Diabetes,
           PDC_HTN,
           PDC_Statins,
           Rating_Diabetes,
           Rating_HTN,
           Rating_Statins,
           M_PC_DB_ORAL,
           M_PC_CV_AA,
           M_PC_CV_LIPO,
           M_PDC_DIABETES,
           M_PDC_HTN,
           M_PDC_STATINS
```

Comment: Did you try printing `rows` before the write to make sure there is actually data in `rows`. This does not sound like `for` loop issue but a query/db issue.

Comment: @Axe319 If I limit the XML query to <= 15 records, `rows` prints out data.  If not, it doesn't print data or create the file.  Is there a limit on how much an object can hold in Python?

Comment: The limit is the amount of memory in your computer. So it is most likely a problem with your query. Can you share the query?

Comment: @Axe319 It is too long so I edited the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If I could, I'd give @Axe319 credit as his idea that it was a database problem was correct.  For some reason, Python didn't like that long XML query, so I incorporated it into the stored procedure.  Then, the Python was like this:

```
  # SQL query for XML data.
  sql_out = """select * from DATA_OUT"""
  cursor.execute(sql_out)
  columns = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
  allRows = cursor.fetchall()

  # Open the file for writing and write the first row.
  xmlFile = open(filename, 'w')
  xmlFile.write('<ROWSET>')

  # Loop through the allRows data set and write it to the file.
  for rows in allRows:
       columnNumber = 0
       for column in columns:
              data = rows[columnNumber]
              if data == None:
                     data = ''
              xmlFile.write('%s' % (data))
              columnNumber += 1

  # Write the final row and close the file.
  xmlFile.write('</ROWSET>')
  xmlFile.close()
```